# which is best library for text to speech and speech to text in angularJS which works for both webpages and .apk,.ipa files?

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, text-to-speech, speech-to-text

Currently I am using webspeech.js whic helps me only for web pages and when I convert my ionic project to .apk file, it doesnt work. Is there any other way which fulfills my requirements? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep your current library for TTS on the browser and use a plugin like [this](https://github.com/vilic/cordova-plugin-tts) for iOS and Android